# How do I clear the "Recent Projects" list in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

> **This question has already an answer here:**
>   [How do you clear your MRU list in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82661/how-do-you-clear-your-mru-list-in-visual-studio) - *7 answers*

How do I remove all the items from the "Recent Project" list in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82661/how-do-you-clear-your-mru-list-in-visual-studio Posting as an answer since OP edited it out of the post.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open the registry, and get rid of the values from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectMRUList` that you don't want.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing the answer while you were doing the duplicate edit. I knew it was in the registry, but took a couple of minutes to find the entry.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me move my recent projects list to my new computer.

Answer (score 3):

Further to Jon Skeet's answer, I have found that you also need to rename the items back to File1, File2 etc.

I deleted the first 3 registry entries, and VS2008 didn't show me any recent projects until I renamed File4 to File 1, File5 to File2 etc.

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution and safer then using the registry to remove individual projects is to rename the .sln file. In VS 2008, click on the project. You will be prompted that it can no longer be found and do you want to remove it from the list.