# Clear Recent Projects list in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know how to clear the Recent Projects list on the start page of VS2015? Apparently VS2015 doesn't have an MRU file in the registry and I can't find any tutorials on how to clear the list for the 2015 version. Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The MRU list just moved for VS 2015. It's still stored in the registry, it's just in a different place.

Open regedit and delete the items in:

**Recent Projects**
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\MRUItems\{a9c4a31f-f9cb-47a9-abc0-49ce82d0b3ac}\Items`

**Recent Files**
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\MRUItems\{01235aad-8f1b-429f-9d02-61a0101ea275}\Items`

Restart Visual Studio and that should do it.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed a nasty bug for me. If you move a solution, but don't change the name, VS2015 spams the old solution item into the taskbar jumplist, with a broken icon. Clearing the recent items fixes this, since it comes from there.

Comment: Works for me. Also note that the first time VS2015 is loaded after deleting the registry items, and if you are using the dark color-scheme, VS has some weird white patches around the edges. Once you open a project, VS updates registry again, so just close and open VS and the white patches will be gone.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Comment: Works perfectly. On a side note, why didn't Microsoft just use \MRUItems\Projects and MRUItems\Files instead of the guids? It's always been a mystery to my why Microsoft makes this needlessly convoluted.

Comment: @mghaoui the guids are com object IDs.

Comment: Oh boy, how oldscool is that. They still keep settings in the registry :-\

Answer (score 21):

To remove a single project from Recent Projects list you can right click on the project and select remove.
(The screenshot is in Italian, but it's clear.)

[image: The screenshot is in Italian but it's clear.]

Comment: Have to restart visual studio to get it removed from the file -> recent project list.

Comment: +1 In my case, immediatly after removing the project from the list, the project disappeared from the sub-menu. This solution is perfect when you just have a couple of recent projects to delete and don't want to go deep into the registry. :)

Comment: This worked once. Then right-clicked ceased to do anything.

Comment: Where can I find that screen in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest solution you could ever found would be the [Clear Recent](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GrzegorzKozub.ClearRecent) VS Extension.

[image]

This extension saved me a lot of time when I moved all the projects from my **HDD** (`D:` partition) to my **SSD** (`P:` partition). I had to remove ~hundred of projects from `Start Page` ***Recent*** *projects* section and I did it in "one click".

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and then type `Clear All`.

Comment: I cant get the CLEAR RECENT menu to come up?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO You need to type `clear` in the ***Quick Launch*** search bar. If the `Clear Recent Menu` doesn't come up, then restart the Visual Studio. If that doesn't help, then reinstall the ***Clear Recent*** extension.