# How do I remove all recent projects list from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I need to remove all recent projects from *Visual Studio 2017 Enterprize*. I prefer to do it from Visual Studio instead of *command prompt*. How can I do that? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear Recent Projects list in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943943/clear-recent-projects-list-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on each and remove from list.

But I'm not aware of any bulk method.

Comment: I knew that how to remove individually projects. I want to remove all. However I have deleted all projects from location so right click doesn't seems to be working.